# State not updating in React Fetch function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spring-boot, bootstrap-4, react-hooks

I have a state, that is set to be either true or false in a fetch statement. When the fetch statement is called, the state is not updated until the second time the submit button is pressed.

It is because of that, that whenever I call an if statement right after, my code automatically navigates to my home page, thinking that the adding of a new account is successful.

When I try to set the state to `null` or `false`, the ternary statement automatically fires off as well.

I've checked the `data` by console logging it, and it comes back as "false" when applicable, but still never updates the state

Any insight on how to approach next?

Edit: The fetch is returning a boolean

```
    let navigate = useNavigate();

    // Error states
    const [successfulAdd, setSuccessfulAdd] = useState(true);


    // Function
    function handleRegister(e) {
        const user = { firstName, lastName, email, password, phone, userName, isAdmin };

        if (password !== passwordConfirm) {
            setPasswordMatch(false);
        } else {
            fetch("http://localhost:8080/user/add", {
                method: "POST",
                headers: { "Content-type": "application/json" },
                body: JSON.stringify(user),
            })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(data => setSuccessfulAdd(data));
        }

        if (successfulAdd) {
            navigate("../home");
        }
    }
.
.
.
    return (
.
.
.
         {/* Username Checker */}
         {successfulAdd ? "" : <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
              The username you've entered has been taken
         </div>}
.
.
.
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "false", a string or boolean?

Comment: A boolean @morganney

Comment: I would remove the `navigate` call inside `handleRegister` and do the `if` check at the top level of your component. If add was successful then navigate, otherwise render your other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since Fetch API and setState are both asynchronous, you might want to put the if statement and all logic inside .then(…)

```
fetch(…)
 .then(res => res.json())
 .then(json => … //navigate here)
 .catch(err => … //set your error state here)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set the initial state to `undefined`.

```
const [successfulAdd, setSuccessfulAdd] = useState(true);
```

Second, add the navigate logic in then of the **fetch request**.

```
 .then(data => { if(data) { navigateTo("./home") } })
```

At last, you can check if `successfulAdd` is `false` then show the user taken message.